# How to assign an webView text content to String Variable

Tags: android

Friend's
     Is there any possibility to assign WebView text content to ordinary String variable?if it so,please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no direct way to do this. If you control the Web page, there are some unpleasant indirect ways to do this. Or, if you do not need to display it to the user, use HttpClient to retrieve the page rather than a `WebView`.